# Is there any way to use advanced Count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables named `team`, `customer`, and `documents`.

```
`team` contains ID, Name

`customer ` contains ID, teamID, Name

`documents ` contains ID, documentID, customerId, Name
```

What i want to achieve is the count of customer per team, and count of customer document.
NB: a customer must have 2 documents, if a customer does not have a document it is regarded as 'incomplete' and vice-versa.

below is the table structure

team table

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Lagos |
| 134 | Abuja |
| 137 | Niger |

customer table

| ID | teamID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | 123 | John |
| 254 | 134 | Hannah |
| 259 | 137 | Josiah |

document table

| ID | documentID | customerId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 354 | 456 | 234 | 47hhhgj.jpg |
| 358 | 466 | 254 | 66tyhgg.pdf |
| 360 | 466 | 234 | 7384848.pdf |
| 362 | 456 | 254 | jf6fjfo.jpg |
| 368 | 466 | 259 | yj77799.pdf |

Result

| team | Number of customer | complete | incomplete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lagos | 200 | 30 | 170 |
| Abuja | 100 | 50 | 50 |

The query used is below:

`SELECT b.team, COUNT(a.Name) FROM customer a inner join team b on a.teamID = b.ID`

but was unable to compute for complete and in complete column and i've tried a lot of approach

So from the `result table`, team `Lagos` as 200 customer, 30 customers have `complete` document
and 170 customers have `incomplete` document etc.
Thanks.

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY b.team`. And you're not joining with `document`.

Comment: How do you count the documents that a customer doesn't have? Do you have a table that lists all the documents, so you can count the ones that are missing for a customer?

Answer (score 0):

First we need to know how to find complete customers.  To this we join the documents to the customer and get the count

```
 SELECT c.ID, c.teamid, count(d.id) as doc_count,
        CASE WHEN count(d.id) >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as complete_flag,
        CASE WHEN count(d.id) >= 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as incomplete_flag
 FROM customer c 
 LEFT JOIN document d on c.ID = d.customerid
 GROUP BY c.ID, c.teamid
```

You can see I also added a flag here for complete and incomplete -- you don't need to calculate both here but I think it is faster to do them both at the same time -- it makes the next query simple:

```
SELECT t.name as team, COUNT(s.id) as num_of_customers,
       SUM(complete_flag) AS complete,
       SUM(incomplete_flag) AS incomplete
FROM team t
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT c.ID, c.teamid, count(d.id) as doc_count,
        CASE WHEN count(d.id) >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as complete_flag,
        CASE WHEN count(d.id) >= 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as incomplete_flag
 FROM customer c 
 LEFT JOIN document d on c.ID = d.customerid
 GROUP BY c.ID, c.teamid
) AS s ON t.id = s.teamid
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

Comment: what i want is the use of  `SQL case`  with `documentID` to check if a customer has documentID 456 and 466 then it will be completed else it will be incompleted. Thanks @Hogan

Comment: @olaniyanoluwasegun -- you can write it yourself then -- just put the criteria in the case statement like I did.  I can say, it is very rare (and almost always wrong) to have a requirement that uses specific record id in the logic.  So it smell to me like you are doing something wrong.